# beamer class how to switch off the \logo image on a specific frame

Tags: beamer

I would use the `\logo` image in most of the frames, but I would like to switch off this image on one particular frame.

Is there a way to obtain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\logo{}` inside a group:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}{}%>>>
  First duck with logo
\end{frame}%<<<
\bgroup
\logo{}%
\begin{frame}{}{}%>>>
  Second duck without.
\end{frame}%<<<
\egroup
\begin{frame}{}{}%>>>
  Third duck with logo.
\end{frame}%<<<
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]